# Output Debug and Trace Messages to Form

Tags: c#, vb.net, trace, listener

My problem is similar to one posed by Joel Coehoorn some time ago when he wanted to [Redirect Trace Output to Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198322/redirect-trace-output-to-console).

In my case, I'd like to output to a ListView or TextBox or for that matter, any control which can accept text. For this purpose, I'd like to have a general purpose Trace/Debug listener which I can hook to in order to process the messages (convert to a ListViewItem or something) before outputting it.

Is there any way I can achieve this or do I have to build my own Trace Listener?

If it's worth noting, I run VS2010 ultimate & VS2008 professional.

Solution should be in preferably be in VB.NET but C# is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) class. [Walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511727.aspx)

You could just implement the Write and WriteLine methods to do this. Initializing it would look something like this:

```
var myTraceListener = new ListViewTraceListener(listView);
Trace.Listeners.Add(myTraceListener);
```

Of course, this is assuming your class has a constructor that accepts a ListView.