# How to Save Console.WriteLine Output to Text File

Tags: c#

I have a program which outputs various results onto a command line console.

How do I save the output to a text file using a `StreamReader` or other techniques?

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test\ntfs8.txt");

foreach (String r in lines.Skip(1))
{
    String[] token = r.Split(',');
    String[] datetime = token[0].Split(' ');
    String timeText = datetime[4];
    String actions = token[2];
    Console.WriteLine("The time for this array is: " + timeText);
    Console.WriteLine(token[7]);
    Console.WriteLine(actions);
    MacActions(actions);
    x = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("================================================");
}

if (x == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The selected time does not exist within the log files!");
}

System.IO.StreamReader reader = ;
string sRes = reader.ReadToEnd();
StreamWriter SW;
SW = File.CreateText("C:\\temp\\test.bodyfile");
SW.WriteLine(sRes);
SW.Close();
Console.WriteLine("File Created");
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mirroring console output to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420429/mirroring-console-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Try this example from this article - [Demonstrates redirecting the Console output to a file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/DemonstratesredirectingtheConsoleoutputtoafile.htm)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

static public void Main ()
{
    FileStream ostrm;
    StreamWriter writer;
    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
    try
    {
        ostrm = new FileStream ("./Redirect.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        writer = new StreamWriter (ostrm);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
        Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
        return;
    }
    Console.SetOut (writer);
    Console.WriteLine ("This is a line of text");
    Console.WriteLine ("Everything written to Console.Write() or");
    Console.WriteLine ("Console.WriteLine() will be written to a file");
    Console.SetOut (oldOut);
    writer.Close();
    ostrm.Close();
    Console.WriteLine ("Done");
}
```

Comment: added this to my standard test console template.

Comment: Is it possible only using app.config, not programmatically, section system.diagnostics ? Any sample?

Comment: Is it not better to use *using* ?

Comment: I wrote a small utility class (`DebugLogger`) that I include in all of my unit tests and initialize as a `private static readonly`. In the `[ClassCleanup]` method I execute `Dispose()`

Comment: I wonder if you can show the output on the console _and_ have it save to a file at the same time.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I have the same question. Were you able to do such?

Answer (score 72):

Try if this works:

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.Create);
var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
Console.SetError(streamwriter);
```

Comment: Great answer - note this *redirects* console output, so you only get logging. Also, you can use FileMode.Append to keep previous logs.

Comment: `Console.SetOut(System.IO.TextWriter.Null)` if you want to turn log off.

Answer (score 26):

For the question:

> How to save Console.Writeline Outputs
>   to text file?

I would use `Console.SetOut` as others have mentioned.

---

However, it looks more like you are keeping track of your program flow. I would  consider using `Debug` or `Trace` for keeping track of the program state.

It works similar the console except you have more control over your input such as `WriteLineIf`.

`Debug` will only operate when in debug mode where as `Trace` will operate in both debug or release mode.

They both allow for listeners such as output files or the console.

```
TextWriterTraceListener tr1 = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(tr1);

TextWriterTraceListener tr2 = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.IO.File.CreateText("Output.txt"));
Debug.Listeners.Add(tr2);
```

-http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788

Answer (score 20):

do you want to write code for that or just use command-line feature 'command redirection' as follows:

***app.exe >> output.txt***

as demonstrated here: http://discomoose.org/2006/05/01/output-redirection-to-a-file-from-the-windows-command-line/ (Archived at [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20060714221335/http://discomoose.org:80/2006/05/01/output-redirection-to-a-file-from-the-windows-command-line/))

EDIT: link dead, here's another example: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/redirect-command-output-to-file.htm

Comment: This solution is better for me because I found that my output was truncated using the TextWriter solution. If you want a fresh link, search for Command Redirection eg. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: Using the redirect feature in e.g. bat/cmd files causes the output to be converted to codepage 850.

Answer (score 7):

Based in the answer by WhoIsNinja:

This code will output both into the Console and into a Log string that can be saved into a file, either by appending lines to it or by overwriting it.

The default name for the log file is 'Log.txt' and is saved under the Application path.

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static StringBuilder LogString = new StringBuilder();
    public static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        LogString.Append(str).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    public static void Write(string str)
    {
        Console.Write(str);
        LogString.Append(str);

    }
    public static void SaveLog(bool Append = false, string Path = "./Log.txt")
    {
        if (LogString != null && LogString.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Append)
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = System.IO.File.AppendText(Path))
                {
                    file.Write(LogString.ToString());
                    file.Close();
                    file.Dispose();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Path))
                {
                    file.Write(LogString.ToString());
                    file.Close();
                    file.Dispose();
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Logger.WriteLine("==========================================================");
Logger.Write("Loading 'AttendPunch'".PadRight(35, '.'));
Logger.WriteLine("OK.");

Logger.SaveLog(true); //<- default 'false', 'true' Append the log to an existing file.
```

Comment: While great, you lose the formatting functionality built into `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 6):

Create a class Logger(code below), replace Console.WriteLine with Logger.Out.
At the end write to a file the string Log

```
public static class Logger
{        
     public static StringBuilder LogString = new StringBuilder(); 
     public static void Out(string str)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(str);
         LogString.Append(str).Append(Environment.NewLine);
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Can't do that for already compiled libraries that print to console directly

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing. 
I usually just create a class, which I can wrap around main in an IDisposable. 
So I can log the console output to a file without modifying the rest of the code.  
That way, I have the output in both the console and for later reference in a text-file.

```
public class Program
{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ConsoleOutputMultiplexer co = new ConsoleOutputMultiplexer())
        {
            // Do something here
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello Logfile and Console 1 !");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello Logfile and Console 2 !");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello Logfile and Console 3 !");
        } // End Using co 


        System.Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    } // End Task Main 

}
```

with

```
public class MultiTextWriter
    : System.IO.TextWriter
{

    protected System.Text.Encoding m_encoding;
    protected System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.TextWriter> m_writers;


    public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding => this.m_encoding;


    public override System.IFormatProvider FormatProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return base.FormatProvider;
        }
    }


    public MultiTextWriter(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.TextWriter> textWriters, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        this.m_writers = textWriters;
        this.m_encoding = encoding;
    }


    public MultiTextWriter(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.TextWriter> textWriters)
        : this(textWriters, textWriters.GetEnumerator().Current.Encoding)
    { }


    public MultiTextWriter(System.Text.Encoding enc, params System.IO.TextWriter[] textWriters)
        : this((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.TextWriter>)textWriters, enc)
    { }


    public MultiTextWriter(params System.IO.TextWriter[] textWriters)
        : this((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.TextWriter>)textWriters)
    { }


    public override void Flush()
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            thisWriter.Flush();
        }
    }

    public async override System.Threading.Tasks.Task FlushAsync()
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            await thisWriter.FlushAsync();
        }

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            thisWriter.Write(buffer, index, count);
        }
    }


    public override void Write(System.ReadOnlySpan<char> buffer)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            thisWriter.Write(buffer);
        }
    }


    public async override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteAsync(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            await thisWriter.WriteAsync(buffer, index, count);
        }

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    public async override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteAsync(System.ReadOnlyMemory<char> buffer, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            await thisWriter.WriteAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
        }

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            thisWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public async override System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            await thisWriter.DisposeAsync();
        }

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {

        foreach (System.IO.TextWriter thisWriter in this.m_writers)
        {
            thisWriter.Close();
        }
        
    } // End Sub Close 


} // End Class MultiTextWriter 



public class ConsoleOutputMultiplexer
    : System.IDisposable
{

    protected System.IO.TextWriter m_oldOut;
    protected System.IO.FileStream m_logStream;
    protected System.IO.StreamWriter m_logWriter;

    protected MultiTextWriter m_multiPlexer;


    public ConsoleOutputMultiplexer()
    {
        this.m_oldOut = System.Console.Out;

        try
        {
            this.m_logStream = new System.IO.FileStream("./Redirect.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            this.m_logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(this.m_logStream);
            this.m_multiPlexer = new MultiTextWriter(this.m_oldOut.Encoding, this.m_oldOut, this.m_logWriter);

            System.Console.SetOut(this.m_multiPlexer);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }

    } // End Constructor 


    void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        System.Console.SetOut(this.m_oldOut);

        if (this.m_multiPlexer != null)
        {
            this.m_multiPlexer.Flush();
            if (this.m_logStream != null)
                this.m_logStream.Flush();

            this.m_multiPlexer.Close();
        }
        
        if(this.m_logStream != null)
            this.m_logStream.Close();
    } // End Sub Dispose 


} // End Class ConsoleOutputMultiplexer
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice solution.

Comment: Love this solution. Works really great with only the minor modiifiication of adding the using statment.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Console.SetOut` to redirect to a `TextWriter` as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using only configuration in your app.config:

```xml
    <system.diagnostics> 
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"> 
              <listeners> 

              <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>

            <!--
            <add name="logListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" /> 
            <add name="EventLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="MyEventLog"/>
             -->

             <!--
              Remove the Default listener to avoid duplicate messages
              being sent to the debugger for display
             -->
             <remove name="Default" />

             </listeners> 
        </trace> 
  </system.diagnostics>
```

For testing, you can use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) before running the program, then we can easily view all of the log messages.

References:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/06/18/configuring-logging-in-a-console-application.aspx
http://www.thejoyofcode.com/from_zero_to_logging_with_system_diagnostics_in_15_minutes.aspx
[Redirect Trace output to Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198322/redirect-trace-output-to-console)
[Problem redirecting debug output to a file using trace listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568630/problem-redirecting-debug-output-to-a-file-using-trace-listener)
https://ukadcdiagnostics.codeplex.com/
http://geekswithblogs.net/theunstablemind/archive/2009/09/09/adventures-in-system.diagnostics.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't this work with Trace.WriteLine and not Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @TomerCagan Maybe using ConsoleTraceListener and Console.SetOut. More info in references.