# Printing newline using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am printing a lot of lines in my log while debugging like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, responseFromServer);
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, t[0]); 
....
```

All of them are getting printed at the same line.. How can i make them print in seperate lines?

I tried using

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, t[0]+"\n");
```

But, it didnt work. Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET the idiom `Environment.NewLine` is a `System.String` that consists of the proper `System.Char`(s) to terminate a line of text, so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, t[0] + Environment.NewLine);
```

---

<sup>*[Updated 2015-05-07]*</sup>

Reflecting upon this a few years on, i feel like i dropped the ball on this at least a little bit (though, i *do* think that it's important to be able to do the low-level NewLine without having to fight the language sometimes as well; so i also like the original answer...)

First off, David Brown did give a good answer below: using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` (and `Write`) instead. That *is* a good solution to this, especially in the case of the OP, as the other parameters of the call aren't even really being used; and the `Debug.Write`/`WriteLine` calls looks like this (using for examples the OP's original calls, assuming for the sake of example that the OP's original first parameter `responseFromServer` was already terminated, and the second needed termination):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(responseFromServer);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t[0]);
```

Easy peasy.

Better yet though, why not `Trace`?

I will just point you to [this stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198322/redirect-trace-output-to-console) but here's the gist.

[You can set up in your App.config but, of course you can also just create it all programatically as well, since the app.config sections simply create objects!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Something like:

```
     ⋮
   <trace>
      <!-- note: notional notation only -->
      <add name="consoleLog" logLevel="debug" enabled="" type="⋯ 
      <add name="netLog" logLevel="verbose" enabled="false" addr="rdp://127.0.0.1:1935/nothing/stream" type="⋯
      <add name="fileLog" logLevel="errors" enabled="true" file="c:\boots.ini" type="⋯ 
   </trace>
     ⋮
```

and then your code calls `Trace()` just like `Debug()`.

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(responseFromServer);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(t[0]);
```

Yep, it's multi-target; and you can set it up to be multi-target, and you can either use built-in `System.Diagnostics` `Trace` types (like a `Console` tracer if you want to print to the screen, for example) or you can create your own custom types as necessary. Beautiful!

Last word: both Debug and Trace have lots of helper functions that are there to make whatever writes you're doing more symbolic; WriteLineIf, TraceError, etc. and it pays to play around with them until you figure out why they are there. It's *almost* guaranteed that the more you *use* them, the more *useful* you will find them. ♡

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` not line break, is this bug?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) documentation, the method has a strange behavior based on settings chosen in Visual Studio. If unmanaged code debugging is enabled, strings output by `Debugger.Log` have a line separator appended. Otherwise, all strings are written on the same line.

You might want to try the various methods of the [`System.Diagnostics.Debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) class instead. There are `Write` methods (that accept newlines) and `WriteLine` methods that append the newline automatically. Both of which also have overloads that accept formatted strings.