# why is my azure webjob not logging to the storage blob?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I've configured app service logging for the app service to go to an azure blob storage.

My test code for the manually-triggered, .net core,  test webjob is simple:

```
namespace TestWebJob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("message using diagnostics");
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to see the Trace logged to the storage blob; but instead my blob is empty after the job runs.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: you should use ILogger rather than Trace.TraceError

Comment: Any more details or examples on implementation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger

Answer (score 0):

### Update......

Sorry for the last answer. I get your point now.

The reason is that we didn't have a `TraceListener` in our code.

You could add this in your code:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

> I found it from the second answer here: [Azure WebJobs: Can't find Trace logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184628/azure-webjobs-cant-find-trace-logging).

> If it didn't work, check your runtime. You can see it is different adding logs in .NET or .NET Core from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#add-log-messages-in-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw1ng.png)

--------------------------------------------------------Dividing line-------------------------------------------------------

I tried to deploy a WebJob using your code, and I found that maybe you should change the log's level in app service log settings to `Verbose`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw1ng.png)

You can see the details in different log's level in this page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0uo.png)

When I set the logs level to `Information` and run the WebJob, there is nothing added in my blob.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bitx.png)

After I change the logs level to `Verbose` and run the WebJob, there are the information added.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX7HV.png)

Comment: Although I didn't quite understand why changing to "verbose" is require to capture TraceError - I tried it anyways. It doesn't seem to make a difference and there are still no log entries in the blob. Also, the screenshots you have don't seem to show the TraceError logged that we expect to see.